# Sharepoint content database user

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

Somebody knows how to change the user account and authentication method sharepoint uses to connect to its content database?
It is now setup to connect using Windows Integrated Authentication but I want to change that to a local user account.

Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint supports [both types of authentication in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx):

1. Windows authentication (the default and preferred choice) - windows credentials are used to authenticate against the SQL server. SharePoint uses IIS which runs sites in an application pool worker process. You can change the credentials for a Web application pool here:

   **`Central Administration > Operations > Service Accounts`**
2. SQL authentication - a username/password combination is created and stored in SQL server. When you create a content database you can choose SQL authentication and then provide the username/password (which you have already created in SQL). If you want to change the auth type of an existing database, you can detach it by checking the remove option on the database settings page (it removes the database from SharePoint but does not delete the actual data). Then you can re-attach the existing database and choose a different auth type. You can manage content databases here:

   **`Central Administration > Application Management > Content Databases`**

Answer (score -2):

you can do it by extending webapplication

The below links will helps you

http://weblog.vb-tech.com/nick/archive/2006/06/14/1617.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/moss_enableforms.aspx

Comment: He doesn't want to change the authentication mode for a SharePoint web application but the user account and authentication mode the web application uses to access its content database. That has nothing to do with form based authentication.

Comment: Correct Flo. IIS stays with Windows Authentication, I want Sharepoint to connect to the database with username-password, not with Windows Authentication. It´s a system that was already setup, needs to be changed now...